# *ngFor fetch json data array object in one page

Tags: angular

This is my first project using Angular2. I don't use any file route in my angular fronEnd I build a API to get data from laravel 5.4 backEnd in json array object with the service:

```
getFoodsByCat(id :number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://livrer/api/menu/' +id)
    .map(
        (response: Response) => { return response.json().foods;
         }
    );}
```

In my component I use this service like this:

```
import {Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Food } from "./food.interface";
import { FoodService } from "./food.service";
    export class FoodsComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() food : Food ;
    foods: Food[];

      constructor(private foodService: FoodService ) { }

        ngOnInit() {
         onGetFoodsByCategorie( id){

        this.foodService.getFoodsByCat(id)
        .subscribe(
        (foods: Food[])=> this.foods = foods,
        (error : Response)=> console.log(error)
        );
          } }
```

This service function gets the json response like this:

```
{"foods":[{"id":10,"designation":"pannin fromage","description":"
Pannini fromage cornichon<\/p>","prix":25,"created_at":"2017-03-11 17:59:34","updated_at":"2017-03-11 ...}]}
```

In the template I use onload the loop start fetch data the first element id=1

```
<ul class="resp-tabs-list">
<li class="active" (load)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(1)">Panninis</li>
<li (click)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(2)">Somthing</li>
<li (click)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(3)">Sandwichs</li>
<li (click)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(4)">Pizzas</li>
</ul>
     <li *ngFor= "let food of foods" [food]="foods">
    //some style and data
    </li>
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'food' since it isn't a known property of 'li'. ("


<li *ngFor= "let food of foods" [ERROR ->][food]="foods">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="thumbnail-menu-modern">  
"): FoodsComponent@26:32
```

Comment: Does your api call a success? It returns data without any error? Did you try it with a console.log()?

Comment: The error is very clear. Remove the [food]="foods" on the list item. I guess you can use ngFor to repeat for foods and display the value in the list item.

Comment: yes my api call a success for exemple ongetfoodcat(1) I rget respnse json:{"foods":[{"id":10,"designation":"pannin fromage","description":"
Pannini fromage cornichon<\/p>","prix":25,"created_at":"2017-03-11 17:59:34","updated_at":"2017-03-11 ....}]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to send data from parent to child component, use @Input. @Input should be set in the child component rather than parent component.

**Parent component**

```
import {Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Food } from "./food.interface";
import { FoodService } from "./food.service";
export class FoodsComponent implements OnInit {
  foods: Food[];
  constructor(private foodService: FoodService ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
     onGetFoodsByCategorie( id){

    this.foodService.getFoodsByCat(id)
    .subscribe(
    (foods: Food[])=> this.foods = foods,
    (error : Response)=> console.log(error)
    );
 }}
```

**Child Component**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-comp',
  template: '<h3>"{{food}}"</h3>'
})
export class ChildComponent {
  private _food = '';
  @Input()
  set food(food: string) {
    this._food = (name && food.trim()) || '<no name set>';
  }
  get food(): string { return this._food; }
}
```

and use the child component selector in the parent template like this. Note that if you want to send each food in the array, use food rather than foods. My example below will send each food to the child element to be displayed. If you want to send foods array to child, just use `<child-comp [food]="foods"></child-comp>`

```
<ul class="resp-tabs-list">
<li class="active" (load)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(1)">Panninis</li>
<li (click)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(2)">Somthing</li>
<li (click)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(3)">Sandwichs</li>
<li (click)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(4)">Pizzas</li>
</ul>
<child-comp *ngFor= "let food of foods" [food]="food"></child-comp>
```